# Associate a file with the FileField without creating a copy of the file?

Tags: python, django

I have the `test.csv` file sitting in `MEDIA_ROOT/file` folder.

I want to associate this file with `FileField` of the following model:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    data = models.FileField()
```

But if I do the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files import File
import os
from .models import Sample

# Create your views here.
def index(request):

    path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, os.path.join('file', 'test.csv'))

    with File(open(path)) as f_obj:

        sample = Sample()
        filename = os.path.basename(f_obj.name)
        sample.data.save(filename, f_obj, save=True)

    return JsonResponse({ 
        'file_url': sample.data.url,
        'file_path': sample.data.path,
        'action': 'Model instance saved to database',
    })
```

a copy of the file will be created in the MEDIA_ROOT directory and this copy - and not the original - will be associated with the model.

Is there a way to not create such copy and just associate the original file with FileField?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to set the `FileField` to your existing file, for a `sample` object, like this:

```
sample = Sample()
file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, 'file', 'test.csv')
sample.data.name = file_path
sample.save()
```

Comment: This will break the URL under which the file is served (full file path will be appended to the media URL instead of only the file name): `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/home/bart/python_projects/testproject/media/file/test.csv`

Comment: Ok, just set it to the correct path `file_path = "media/file/test.csv"` (or try `MEDIA_URL` instead of `MEDIA_ROOT` if you have it defined).